# Узнать число битового сдвига влево

Tags: битовые-операции

Через оператор << мы получаем определенное десятеричное число путем битового сдвига влево. Например, 1 << 6 = 64. Если рассматривать данную операцию в двоичном представлении, то станет ясно, что мы технически переносим цифру 1 на 6 единиц влево.
0000000000000001 << 6 = 0000000001000000

Но как получить обратное значение? Предположим, у нас есть число 64 и нам нужно получить из него значение 6, т.е. фактически узнать насколько нам нужно сдвинуть биты вправо, что бы получить 1. Конечно, можно было бы перевести число 64 в двоичную систему, а затем работать с числом как со строкой, подсчитать количество нулей после единицы и получить результат. Но хотелось бы более производительное решение. Желательно на javascript синтаксисе.

Answer (score 2):

Эта операция - банальное вычисление логарифма по основанию 2.

так что

```
Math.log2(x);
```

-все что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Данная задача сводится к нахождению позиции бита, равного 1, и может быть решена подсчетом требуемого количества сдвигов вправо. Например (на C):

```
int bitpos(unsigned x) {
    int pos = -1;
    while (x != 0) {
        ++pos;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Эта функция вернет позицию последнего бита, равного 1 (оговорка на случай, если единичный бит не один) или -1, если все биты равны 0.